# http access for only 1 domain name

Tags: php, html

so i have loads of domain names on 1 hosting plan but have a main one in my root i am using http acess

```
options -multiviews
options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
   RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php
   RewriteRule ^advertiser$ advertiser.php
   RewriteRule ^add_campaign$ add_campaign.php
   RewriteRule ^edit_campaign$ edit_campaign.php
   RewriteRule ^stats$ view_statistics.php
   RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
   RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
   RewriteRule ^withdrawals$ withdrawals.php
   RewriteRule ^register$ register.php
   RewriteRule ^report$ report.php
   RewriteRule ^referrals$ referrals.php
   RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
   RewriteRule ^add_wallet$ add_wallet.php
   RewriteRule ^payment_page$ payment_page.php
   RewriteRule ^forgot_password$ forgot_password.php
   RewriteRule ^my_account$ my_account.php
   RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ view_link.php?s=$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^page_([^/]+)/?$ pages.php?slug=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rest of my domain names will now not work because it will not let me access any of the files by doing **domainname.com/folder** is there any way to set these rules just for the main domain name??

Comment: each domain should have its own web root

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `RewriteCode` that matches the main domain name. Like this

```
options -multiviews
options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourmaindomain.com$
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
   RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php
   RewriteRule ^advertiser$ advertiser.php
   RewriteRule ^add_campaign$ add_campaign.php
   RewriteRule ^edit_campaign$ edit_campaign.php
   RewriteRule ^stats$ view_statistics.php
   RewriteRule ^login$ login.php
   RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php
   RewriteRule ^withdrawals$ withdrawals.php
   RewriteRule ^register$ register.php
   RewriteRule ^report$ report.php
   RewriteRule ^referrals$ referrals.php
   RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
   RewriteRule ^add_wallet$ add_wallet.php
   RewriteRule ^payment_page$ payment_page.php
   RewriteRule ^forgot_password$ forgot_password.php
   RewriteRule ^my_account$ my_account.php
   RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ view_link.php?s=$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^page_([^/]+)/?$ pages.php?slug=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then the rewrite rules should only run if the domain matches.